# Counting MySQL rows, stopping people from entering characters

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how I could stop people from doing this; `blahblah.com/index.php?id=../../file.php`

I was told I could stop this from happening by counting mysql rows...?

Comment: Thre is not much sense in this question. What type this `id` parameter is supposed to be? If it's numeric identifier from the database, `../../file.php` will do no harm. and counting rows has especially nothing to do here. Can you ask more certain question? Do you experience any problems right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : false;

if ($id) {
    // do your thing..
} else {
    echo 'invalid item..';
}
```

IF $_GET['id'] isn't set, or it's 0 then "invalid item" will be displayed. The (int) will also cast strings to 0.

Another solution:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false;

if ($id && is_numeric($id)) {
    // run mysql query here
} else {
    echo 'Invalid item..';
}
```

Comment: `if ($id && is_numeric($id))` : The `is_numeric` function will return false even if the value is not defined, meaning the double check is not necessary

Comment: You need to check if the value is set first, otherwise you'll get an undefined notice.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use PHPs `is_numeric` on `$_GET['id']`, or force the id to a number

Comment: So something like if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ?

Comment: To **test** if it's a number you can use `is_numeric($_GET['id'])`, to **convert** it to a number assign `(int)$_GET['id']` to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can check first if it's a numeric value like Nayena said, then you can use a MySQL request to check the row count on this id. If it's 1, then it's valid, otherwise there is a problem in the request

EDIT (Example) :

```
<?php
if(is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id=".$id));
    if($count == 1)
    {
        //Id is valid, moving on...
    }
    elseif($count == 0)
    {
        //Id doesn't exist, display error message
    }
    else
    {
        //Id exists more than 1 time, meaning there is a serious issue.
        //Display error message or send email to webmaster
    }
}
else
{
    //Display error message (incorrect format for example)
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain how to do it? I'm still very much a learner.